# superfluous separation of the text in a dropdown menu in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon, a question in the following, using Bootstrap made a dropdown menu, when clicking the menu the Tex is selected and the dropdown menu, and a problem in that is closed that in case of repeated clicking the menu of separation doesn't disappear (as on a screenshot)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEnEl.png)

for some reason after clicking the class = active though anywhere in js I don't do it is added. Here my code:

```
<div id = "divAddRightUsers">
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7">one:</label>
  <div class = "btn-group">
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id = "accOOH" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Тип<span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#" id = "accOOHIsNoAccess" >Нет доступа</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id = "accOOHReadings" >Только чтение</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id = "accOOHEdition">Редактирование</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id = "accOOHExpandedAccess">Расширенный доступ</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I coped with it so:

```
.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus{
    color: #151111;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    outline: 0px none;
    }
```

but it would be desirable to learn for what reason it is added to  and isn't deleted on closing of the menu? When checking all js code cleaned, it is definitely not guilty.

P.S Excuse for grammatical errors and another, I badly know English.

Comment: I think you are asking about why the `active` class is applied on drop down options, but it isn't removed. However, I am unable to replicate the issue you are having. see this http://jsfiddle.net/q5Lztj6x/ do you have other CSS that may be interfering ?

Comment: I too so thought, but I cleaned all but Bootstrap I cleaned all but and also checked in an online service, and everywhere works except my project....

Comment: Some CSS is getting added - use developer tools to inspect the element and see all the classes being added. Post how you are adding the jquery js and css to your page